# Grand total pivot table range reference for excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to simply get the value of the grand total of a pivot table. However I need this to be more dynamic than the solution found online.

[image]

A simple solution that I have seen online was to get the last cell found in the range of the grand total column. In this case, resulting to something like the code mentioned below.

```
Dim grandTotal As Range
grandTotal = Range("E65536").End(xlUp)
MsgBox grandTotal.Value
```

However, this would simply fail if I had some data filled in below the pivot table, in the same column. Is there a way to precisely reference the grand total value? Maybe like referencing the data range of the two grand total column and row, and find an intersect between the two to get the cell highlighted in yellow?

Edit:

What about getting the grand total for the two different data value columns

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since it would be the most bottom right cell in your pivot table:

```
Set pt = Activesheet.PivotTables(1)
grandTotal = pt.DataBodyRange.Cells(pt.DataBodyRange.Cells.Count).Value
```

Comment: This would work if there was only one data value placed in the pivot table. would like to know what if I had two data values each having their own separate grand total column. How would I get the two different grand total values respectively?

Comment: Do you mean you would like to get the total of of East and West for example? If not, best to show an example in your question (edit it)

Comment: I could just continue using your example and just take the second last cell in the data range I guess, if there is no specific way in distinguishing those grand total cells.

Comment: `pt.DataBodyRange.Cells(pt.DataBodyRange.Cells.Count -1).Value` would give you that value :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reference different Rows or Columns Totals, this way should work well for you.

```
Sub SelectGrandTotal()
  Dim pt As PivotTable
  Dim rGrandTotal As Range
  
  Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
  
  With pt
  
    'This condition checks if the GrandTotals are activated. Not really necessary in some cases.
    If .ColumnGrand And .RowGrand Then
      With .DataBodyRange
      
        'Add "- 1" after ".Count" if you want to move between different Totals.
        Set rGrandTotal = .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
        rGrandTotal.Select
        'Print
        MsgBox (rGrandTotal)

      End With

    End If

  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following approach. My pivot table is as follows:

```
...
Dim strSourceData As String
strSourceData = "'SAP Dump'!R1C1:R" & Trim$(Str$(lr)) & "C9"

wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=strSourceData, _
         Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "Pivot!R2C2", TableName:="Pivot_Proj_MA", DefaultVersion:=6
    
Set pt = ws.PivotTables("Pivot_Proj_MA")
With pt.PivotFields("Receiver WBS Element")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With pt.PivotFields( _
    "Name of employee or applicant")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With

pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("Number (Unit)"), "Sum of Number (Unit)", xlSum
...
```

To get the sums, try this (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.getdata)

```
Set pt = ws.PivotTables("Pivot_Proj_MA")
Debug.Print pt.GetData("'Sum of Number (Unit)' K-020979-100 'HUBER ANDREAS'")
                               =                     =               =
                            DataField              RowField        RowField
```

If you use only the datafield, you get the sum of this field.

```
Debug.Print pt.GetData("'Sum of Number (Unit)'")
```