# get Pivot Value (Grand Total ) using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Pivot Table and I want a value from that Pivot Table which is the Grand Total value.
If you see the below picture, I want the value "88%". This value is in cell C24 .
And it is in the Compliance Field (Column C) and the row is the Grand Total.
Above the Pivot Table I already have the filters applied for filtering my data. I just want the vba code for this cell/field value.
This is what I tried.

```
Dim rtot as Double
rtot = Worksheets("ABC").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotValueCell(3, 24).Value
```

[image]

Comment: You will do better to reference the `DataBodyRange` of the pivot table, as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55723272/4717755)

Comment: Take a look here for how to reference regions in a pivot table - https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/

Comment: Thanks @PeterT ......I modified the code according to the link you shared and it worked.

Comment: Thank you @TimWilliams. This is very useful.

Answer (score 4):

I changed my  code using the link in the comments and it worked. So just sharing it so that its useful for other people.

```
Set pt = Worksheets("ABC").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
            rtot = pt.DataBodyRange.Cells(pt.DataBodyRange.Cells.Count).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Evaluate on the Getpivotdata formula:

```
rtot = Application.Evaluate("=GETPIVOTDATA(""COMPLIANCE %"",ABC!$A$13)")
```

Change cell address and sheet to yours (topleftcell of pivot)